# <object> responsive width

Tags: html, css

In my fixed version site I have :

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="uppod.swf" width="560" height="370">
```

How do item tag `<object>` is responsive ?

```
object{
    width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

It doesn't work .

How change attributes `width="560" height="370"` ?

Comment: Don't change them, just remove them and let the CSS handle the sizing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove width and height attributes here:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="uppod.swf">
```

and in CSS:

```
object {
     width:100%;
     max-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The HTML settings override CSS. Remove them from your HTML tag and set them only in CSS.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="uppod.swf">
```