# HTML how to fix objects on one postion regardless of window size?

Tags: html, css

I am very new to HTML.

I am trying to put two objects on one page but they are moving around when the window are resizing.
How can I fixed them in one position so they are positioned regardless of the window size.

'''

```
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object data="block1_pie.html" width="450" height="800"></object>
        <object data="block2_sixplots.html" width="900" height="800"></object>
    </body>
```

'''

Comment: Your title HMTL is wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<object> responsive width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300369/object-responsive-width)

Comment: Rick.Wang Thank!

Comment: Justinas Thank!, but this makes two objects align vertically. How can I align them horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you are trying to fix them in a position so that they don't move but as window size resizes, you can scroll. To do that simply set a defined width to body element. Like this.

```
<head>
</head>
<body style="min-width: 1400px">
    <object data="block1_pie.html" width="450" height="800"></object>
    <object data="block2_sixplots.html" width="900" height="800"></object>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need position property in css;

[Look at code from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)